# Gauge transformation on vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum

Suppose we have two electromagnetic vector potential operator that differ  by a gauge transformation in free field theory.

$A'_{\mu}= A_{\mu}-\partial_{\mu}\alpha$

is the state

$A_{\mu}|0\rangle$

equal to the state

$A'_{\mu}|0\rangle$

if so why?

Comment: The object $\alpha$ is not a classical field of the theory, therefore it is not mapped to a quantum operator by any canonical quantization process, and therefore it is unclear what you mean when you write it down as if it could act on the quantum state $\lvert 0\rangle$. The question is ill-posed.

Comment: so you mean that the gauge transformation is made classically than we do the quantization?

Comment: Your edit doesn't really address the problem: $A'$ is not a distinct classical field, it denotes a different *configuration* of the field. But we do not quantize particular field configurations, we quantize *the field*. Go back to ordinary quantum mechanics, there an analogous question would be to ask how the action of $x_0$ (as a value of the position variable $x$) differs from the action of a different value $x'_0$ on a state, which is an equally ill-posed question because we do not assign operators to particular values (=configurations) of the classical variables.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira You might want to look at BRST invariance. From this perspective, you have an initial Hilbert space in which a pure gauge transformation *does* change the vector to something different. However, you identify physical states with equivalence classes of vectors that are invariant under pure gauge transformations.

Answer (score -1):

In a paper authored by myself ( https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078) I promote the idea that electromagnetic gauge invariance is an unnecessary restriction on the theory. I do not require invariance under arbitrary gauge transformations and still get a physically correct theory. Of course, the Lorentz force is recovered, so the force depends only on  E and B. However the potential is uniquely determined by the source.

This theory allows electromagnetic spin to be treated as a separate mechanical observable, something that the gauge invariant theory precludes. It also avoids the numerous paradoxes associated with conservation laws, see for example Feynman's Lectures II ch 27. Notably, questions like the one at hand here do not pop up.

I think this approach deserves much more attention from the physical community. However, it is very hard if not impossible to start a discussion on the lack of physical meaning of gauge invariance. In fact, field theorists are "Under the spell of the gauge principle" and any doubt on its relevance seems simply off the map.

Comment: You might be interested that Dirac uses the "Fermi Lagrangian", equation (2) in your paper, to quantize the free E-M field in his "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory", published by Belfer Graduate School of Science 1966. The Fermi Lagrangian is equation (15.3) on page 74.

Comment: @Stephen Blake Thank you for pointing that out! The lagrangian was not used by Fermi in his original paper, but he did use the wave equation. This was formalised by defining the Fermi lagrangian but I have no reference for this.